# Can't install pychalk: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\MarkupSafe-1.1.1.dist-info\\METADATA"'

Tags: python, pip, python-3.8

I'm getting the following error when trying to install pychalk:

```
pip install pychalk --user
```

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\jokzc\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python38\\site-packages\\MarkupSafe-1.1.1.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

Comment: Is that the entire error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Python 3.8.

> ...python\\python38\\site-packages\...

The [last release for pychalk](https://pypi.org/project/pychalk/#history) was 2018, before the [releases for Python3.8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0569/#schedule) came out.
The package is probably not updated yet to support Python 3.8.

You will have to downgrade your Python version.

From the repo's README on [**Testing**](https://github.com/anthonyalmarza/chalk#testing), it seems they only tested on 2.7, 3.5, 3.6.
I tried it and it seems it can also install successfully on Python 3.7.

So...

- Use Python3.7
- [Report the issue](https://github.com/anthonyalmarza/chalk/issues) to the package authors so that they can support Python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

you just need to delete the OpenCV-python folder from the(path=**C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\opencv_python-3.4.2.17.dist-info**) and then again you have to install that library
you can see the picture below.
here I have attached two pics in which first is showing error messages
and the second one is not showing any errors

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDhV3.png)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZe18.png)